# Shortcut to file permissions

Tags: shortcut, file-permissions

I have two mapped drives on our server (M & P, management and public) with rights for everyone on P and only rights for management on M.

We now have team leads who have to access just a few folders on M.  Is it possible to create a shortcut on P to the needed folders on M which would allow the Team Leads to access the just files they need on M?  For instance the Team Lead needs access to M:\Ops\Schedules (and the files within the Schedule folder).  I would like to create a shortcut on P to M:\Ops\Schedules allowing the Team LEad to open the Schedule folder.

I have tried adding the Team Lead group (which have read and execute permissions) to both the shortcut and the folder where the files reside but I get an error message saying that the user does not have sufficient rights.

TIA,

Brian Enderle

Comment: No advice on this ??

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask this question at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), since this seems more of a server administration question than a programming one.

But to attempt answer your question, assuming the shares are Windows file shares, you would need to check two things: that the permissions of M:\Ops\Schedules are set so that members of the Team Leads group have access to the directory, and that the share permissions of the Management share are set so Team Leads have (at minimum) read access.  If either of these are not present, team leaders will be denied access to the directory.

As an alternative, you could create a new share on the server that points to \Ops\Schedules, and give team leads access to this share.  You could then create a shortcut on P: directly to that share.  Team Leads will need access (through NTFS permissions) to the \Ops\Schedules directory.

Either approach should work, and the one to use might depend on whether you are relying primarily on NTFS permissions or share permissions to secure your file shares.